# Excel 2007: conditional formatting for certain cells?

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements, highlight

What I need to do is conditionally format the below cells to highlight the lowest value.

```
B2, H2, G2, M2, R2, W2, AB2, AG2, AL2
```

But I need to do this about 50 times, and again for another set but for the next field(B3, H3 .. etc)
Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: You could try using a Named Range?

Comment: There is no option to insert a cell range for the conditional formatting as far as I can see.The only method to format cells conditionally that I have found is to manually highlight them, and use the "conditional formatting" button at the top.

Comment: To define a range you can set up a new rule. Then go to the conditional formatting Manage Rules and modify the `Applies To` Range. Is there a pattern to your Range? Like you are looking at Every 5 Columns?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to do:

Click on B2

Control click H2, G2 etc

Enter a conditional format based on a formula and use the following formula:

```
=B2=MIN($B2, $H2, $G2, $M2, $R2, $W2, $AB2, $AG2, $AL2)
```

Copy any one of these cells and paste special format only into any other cell where you want it applied.

Comment: You could also use the built in `Bottom X Values` in Conditional Format. But I think the scope of this question was not how to format that range. But a better way to select the cells without manually doing it. As OA has 2 sets of 50 Ranges and doesn't want to manually have to select every value. Although, I could be wrong.

Comment: What exactly is the formula doing? Setting B2 equal to the value of the minimum of a range of values?

Comment: To user2140261 - I think it is a question on how to format the range, the trick with conditional formats is knowing where and when to use absolute vs relative references to make it easy to copy to another location. My formula could be entered into just cell B2 followed by highlighting B3:B52, H2:H2, G2:G52 etc and then a paste special. That's one formula entry and one paste special operation - you are not going to get it much quicker than that.

Comment: I can get this to work on one line. If I attempt to paste special: formula, every value in the row is overwritten to the value of whatever value was in the cell I copied.

Comment: To sherrellbc - No its a formula for a conditional format that applies whatever formatting you decide when the formula evaluates to true. In this example it is saying if the current cell (B2) is equal to lowest value in the range apply your formatting.

Comment: It should be **Paste Special > Formats**. Or, in the Conditional Formatting dialog just adjust the "Applies To" box.

Comment: To sherrellbc - Sorry not paste special formula - try paste special format